# Laravel Inertia redirect back url when doing a post

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

So I have a description page that has favorite button in it, when pressed it will passes `id`, `content`, `favorite` value to controller function `addFav`, and do the checking inside the function.
The problem is when I want to returns it back to the description page, the url still containing a favorite value (true or false), how do I remove the parameter on the URL ?

**Component methods of favorite button**

```
methods: {
        toggleFav(id, content) {
            //Everytime button is clicked, change the value of the isFavorite to manipulate button style
            // console.log("Current Favourited ID = " + VueCookies.get("FavId"));
            let state = "";
            this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
            console.log(this.stateProps);
            this.saveFav(id, content, this.stateProps);
        },
        saveFav(id, content, state) {
            const currentCookies = [VueCookies.get("FavId")];
            let arrayCookies = [];
            console.log(state);
            //Check if the state of the user
            //if its offline then show an alert with the confirmation message that data is saved locally
            if (state == "offline") {
                if (!this.confirmState) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: "You are offline",
                        text: "Your data is saved locally, if you want to save your bookmarks online please login",
                        icon: "info",
                        reverseButtons: true,
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        cancelButtonColor: "#049806",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#0B1C11",
                        cancelButtonText: "Login",
                        confirmButtonText: "Stay offline",
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result["isConfirmed"]) {
                            // console.log("Confirmed");
                            // this.confirmState = "offline";
                            VueCookies.set("offlineState", "true");
                            this.$inertia.get(
                                this.route("plantCharacteristic")
                            );
                        } else {
                            this.$inertia.get(this.route("login"));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            //check if it is favorite
            if (this.isFavorite) {
                let favorite = true;
                //set the cookie to id passed
                arrayCookies.push(currentCookies);
                arrayCookies.push(id);
                VueCookies.set("FavId", decodeURI(arrayCookies));
                const fav = this.$inertia.post(
                    this.route("addfavDB", [content, id, favorite])
                );
                // console.log("UID : " + id + " Favourited");
            } else {
                let favorite = false;
                //if the favorite button pressed again it will remove the current id in the cookie
                //without removing all the cookies
                const removeCookies = currentCookies.toString();
                const removed = removeCookies.replace(id, "");
                VueCookies.set("FavId", decodeURI(removed));
                this.$inertia.post(
                    this.route("addfavDB", [content, id, favorite])
                );
                // console.log("UID : " + id + " UnFavorited");
            }
        },
    },
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('docs', [PlantsController::class, "index"])->name('plants');
Route::post('docs', [PlantsController::class, "index"])->name('plants');
Route::controller(PlantCharacteristicController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('docs/desc', [PlantCharacteristicController::class, "index"])->name('plantCharacteristic');
    Route::post('docs/desc', [PlantCharacteristicController::class, "index"])->name('plantCharacteristic');
    Route::post('docs/desc/content={content}&id={id}&{favorite}', [PlantCharacteristicController::class, "addFav"])->name('addfavDB');

});
```

**Controller function addFav**

```
public function addFav(){
        $id = request('id');
        $content = request('content');
        $favorite = filter_var(request('favorite'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) ;
        $plants = $this->getTableName('plants');
        $algae = $this->getTableName('algae');
        $nutrientDef = $this->getTableName('nutrient_deficiencies');

        $payload = $this->checkContent($id, $content);
        $user = Auth::user();

        if(!$user){
            // dd('You are offline');
            return $this->redirectDesc($plants,$algae,$nutrientDef,$content,$payload);
            // return redirect()->back();


        }else{
            if($favorite){

                if($this->checkFavorite($content, $user, $id)){
                    dd('This Plants is already in the favorites list');

                }else{
                    $this->addFavorite($content, $user, $id);
                    // dd('added to db');

                    return $this->redirectDesc($plants,$algae,$nutrientDef,$content,$payload);
                }

            }else{
                $this->removeFavorite($content, $user, $id);
                // dd('removed from db');
                return $this->redirectDesc($plants,$algae,$nutrientDef,$content,$payload);

            }
        }
    }
```

**Controller function redirectDesc**

```
public function redirectDesc($plants, $algae, $nutrientDef, $contentDesc, $payload){
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user){
            return Inertia::render('Components/Plants/PlantCharacteristic', [
                        'plants' => $plants,
                        'algae' => $algae,
                        'nutrientDef' => $nutrientDef,
                        'content' => $contentDesc,
                        'payload' => $payload,
                        'state' => "online"
                    ]);
        }else{
            return Inertia::render('Components/Plants/PlantCharacteristic', [
                        'plants' => $plants,
                        'algae' => $algae,
                        'nutrientDef' => $nutrientDef,
                        'content' => $contentDesc,
                        'payload' => $payload,
                        'state' => "offline"
                    ]);
        }
    }
```

How do I write the redirect on `redirectDesc()` function to redirect to

`http://domain.test/docs/desc/content={content}&id={id}`

not

`http://domain.test/docs/desc/content={content}&id={id}&{favorite}`

on the URL after I press the favorite button